# I am creating a new JFrame with action Listener but am unable to change the background color

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I have been working numerous hours on creating a new JFram with actionlistener but I am unable to change the background color of my frame. I have tried panels, getContentPane(), etc. Currently the buy window displays everything I want it to,but the background is white and I have been trying to change it to gray.

Below is my code.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
//import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUIroughdraft {

private JFrame frmBgszStockSimulator;
/**
 * @wbp.nonvisual location=53,14
 */
//private final JLabel lblBgszStockSimulator = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createTitle("BGSZ Stock Simulator");
private  JTextField searchBar;
private JTable table;
private  JTextField displayBox;
private  JButton searchButton;

/**
 * Launch the application. Testing Comment
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GUIroughdraft window = new GUIroughdraft();
            try {
                window = new GUIroughdraft();
                window.frmBgszStockSimulator.setVisible(true);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GUIroughdraft() {
    try {
        initialize();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void initialize() throws IOException 
{
    frmBgszStockSimulator = new JFrame();
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setTitle("BGSZ Stock Simulator");
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setBounds(100, 100, 802, 510);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);
    mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
            saveFile.setSelectedFile(new File(".csv"));
            saveFile.showSaveDialog(null);
        }
    });

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);
    mntmLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
                openFile.showOpenDialog(null);
            }
        });

    JMenuItem mntmOptions = new JMenuItem("Options");
    mnFile.add(mntmOptions);

    JMenu mnActions = new JMenu("Actions");
    menuBar.add(mnActions);

    JMenuItem mntmBuy = new JMenuItem("Buy");
    mnActions.add(mntmBuy);
    mntmBuy.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                JFrame frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy = new JFrame();
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.setTitle("Buy Stocks");
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.setVisible(true);
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
                JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(p);
                p.setBackground(Color.gray);//To set panel background instead of frames background
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.add(p);

                searchBar = new JTextField();
                searchBar.setText("Enter your text here");
                searchBar.setBounds(12, 300, 300, 22);
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(searchBar);
                searchBar.setColumns(10);

                JTextArea displayBox = new JTextArea();
                displayBox.setEditable(false);
                displayBox.setLineWrap(true);
                displayBox.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                displayBox.setText("This will be a text field that displays all your actions and information about stocks, purchases, sales, errors, etc.");

                displayBox.setBounds(12, 47, 312, 317);
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(displayBox);          

            }


        });

    JMenuItem mntmSell = new JMenuItem("Sell");
    mnActions.add(mntmSell);

    JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp);

    JMenuItem mntmInfo = new JMenuItem("Info");
    mnHelp.add(mntmInfo);

    JMenuItem mntmAbout = new JMenuItem("How to Use");
    mnHelp.add(mntmAbout);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    scrollBar.setBounds(323, 47, 21, 317);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);

    JTextArea displayBox = new JTextArea();
    displayBox.setEditable(false);
    displayBox.setLineWrap(true);
    displayBox.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    displayBox.setText("This will be a text field that displays all your actions and information about stocks, purchases, sales, errors, etc.");

    displayBox.setBounds(12, 47, 312, 317);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(displayBox);

    searchBar = new JTextField();
    searchBar.setText("Enter your text here");
    searchBar.setBounds(12, 377, 637, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(searchBar);
    searchBar.setColumns(10);

    JButton searchButton = new JButton();
    searchButton.setText("Search");
    searchButton.setBounds(654, 377, 93, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(searchButton);
    searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         {

             String userInput = searchBar.getText();

                    GetStockData gd = new GetStockData();
                    try 
                    {
                        gd.pullPriceData(userInput);

                    } 
                    catch (IOException er) 
                    {
                        er.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    String output = Double.toString(gd.getPrice());;
                    if(output == "0")
                    {
                        displayBox.setText("NO STOCK FOUND");
                    }
                    displayBox.setText("The Price for " + userInput + ": $" + output);
                    //get to print in the table.
                    //userInput = stock ticker 
                    //ouput = price
            }
      });

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    progressBar.setValue(75);
    progressBar.setBounds(50, 412, 586, 14);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"Stock Name", "Stock Value", "Amount Owned", "Total Value"},
                {" BAC", "$13.48", "4", "$53.92"},
                {" RIG", "$8.89", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" SUNE", "$0.59", "12", "$7.08"},
                {" FCX", "$10.29", "2", "$20.58"},
                {" PBR", "$5.86", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" GE", "$31.83", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" VALE", "$4.24", "24", "$101.76"},
                {" VRX", "$27.07", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" PFE", "$30.07", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" CRC", "$1.05", "8", "$8.40"},
                {" GGB", "$1.82", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" CHK", "$4.01", "6", "$24.06"},
                {" T", "$39.37", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" F", "$13.35", "5", "$66.75"},
                {" WLL", "$7.66", "0", "$0.00"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        ));
    table.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    table.setBounds(350, 51, 395, 313);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(table);

    JTextArea txtrValue = new JTextArea();
    txtrValue.setText("Displays Cash Value");
    txtrValue.setLineWrap(true);
    txtrValue.setEditable(false);
    txtrValue.setBounds(99, 12, 172, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(txtrValue);

    JTextArea txtrCurrentPortfolioValue = new JTextArea();
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setText("Display Portfolio Value");
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setLineWrap(true);
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setEditable(false);
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setBounds(376, 12, 206, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(txtrCurrentPortfolioValue);

    JLabel lblCashValue = new JLabel("Cash Value:");
    lblCashValue.setBounds(24, 15, 111, 16);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(lblCashValue);

    JLabel lblPortfolioValue = new JLabel("Portfolio Value:");
    lblPortfolioValue.setBounds(283, 15, 123, 16);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(lblPortfolioValue);
}

/*  private class customListener implements ActionListener {
    private GUIroughdraft window;

    public customListener(GUIroughdraft window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String userInput = window.searchBar.getText();
            GetStockData gd = new GetStockData();
            try {
                gd.pullPriceData(userInput);
            } catch (IOException er) {
                er.printStackTrace();
            }
            String output = Double.toString(gd.getPrice());
            window.displayBox.setText("The Price for " + userInput + ":" + output);
    }
}*/
```

Comment: the better is to import only packages with all class:
import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.event.*; import java.awt.*;

Comment: default color  of all panels, and frames are gray, change color

Comment: I'd disagree with @GlacialMan that it's better to import packages. If you import classes (and the IDE automates it) then it's much easier to find out where you have references to a particular class with `git grep` or equivalent. Of course if you don't have an IDE then it's probably tedious to do so.

Comment: I didn't thought about that. Maybe you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the LayoutManager that you are using. The default layout manager for Frame is [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). When you added the displayBox to frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy in the statement `frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(displayBox)`. It was added at the center of the frame with the constraint `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Hence it got resized to the full size of the frame as soon as the Frame was resized. When I changed the statement as specified with the second parameter as PAGE_CHART, the displayBox is added at PAGE_START:

```
 frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(displayBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

You can see the color GRAY that you set after making this change. Change the code as above to see the background color you applied to the Frame. You can read more about the BorderLayout [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).
Here is the complete code that I used to test. I commented some of your code that I could not compile.

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GUIroughdraft {

private JFrame frmBgszStockSimulator;
/**
 * @wbp.nonvisual location=53,14
 */
//private final JLabel lblBgszStockSimulator = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createTitle("BGSZ Stock Simulator");
private  JTextField searchBar;
private JTable table;
private  JTextField displayBox;
private  JButton searchButton;

/**
 * Launch the application. Testing Comment
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GUIroughdraft window = new GUIroughdraft();
            try {
                window = new GUIroughdraft();
                window.frmBgszStockSimulator.setVisible(true);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GUIroughdraft() {
    try {
        initialize();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void initialize() throws IOException 
{
    frmBgszStockSimulator = new JFrame();
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setTitle("BGSZ Stock Simulator");
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setBounds(100, 100, 802, 510);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frmBgszStockSimulator.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);
    mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
            saveFile.setSelectedFile(new File(".csv"));
            saveFile.showSaveDialog(null);
        }
    });

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);
    mntmLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
                openFile.showOpenDialog(null);
            }
        });

    JMenuItem mntmOptions = new JMenuItem("Options");
    mnFile.add(mntmOptions);

    JMenu mnActions = new JMenu("Actions");
    menuBar.add(mnActions);

    JMenuItem mntmBuy = new JMenuItem("Buy");
    mnActions.add(mntmBuy);
    mntmBuy.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                JFrame frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy = new JFrame();
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.setTitle("Buy Stocks");
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.setVisible(true);
                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
//                JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
//                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(p);
//                p.setBackground(Color.gray);//To set panel background instead of frames background
//                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.add(p);
//
//                searchBar = new JTextField();
//                searchBar.setText("Enter your text here");
//                searchBar.setBounds(12, 300, 300, 22);
//                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(searchBar);
//                searchBar.setColumns(10);
//
                JTextArea displayBox = new JTextArea();
                displayBox.setEditable(false);
                displayBox.setLineWrap(true);
                displayBox.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                displayBox.setText("This will be a text field that displays all your actions and information about stocks, purchases, sales, errors, etc.");
//
                displayBox.setBounds(12, 47, 312, 317);

                frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(displayBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);   //This is where BorderLayout.PAGE_START is added.       

            }


        });

    JMenuItem mntmSell = new JMenuItem("Sell");
    mnActions.add(mntmSell);

    JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp);

    JMenuItem mntmInfo = new JMenuItem("Info");
    mnHelp.add(mntmInfo);

    JMenuItem mntmAbout = new JMenuItem("How to Use");
    mnHelp.add(mntmAbout);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    scrollBar.setBounds(323, 47, 21, 317);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);

    JTextArea displayBox = new JTextArea();
    displayBox.setEditable(false);
    displayBox.setLineWrap(true);
    displayBox.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    displayBox.setText("This will be a text field that displays all your actions and information about stocks, purchases, sales, errors, etc.");

    displayBox.setBounds(12, 47, 312, 317);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(displayBox);

    searchBar = new JTextField();
    searchBar.setText("Enter your text here");
    searchBar.setBounds(12, 377, 637, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(searchBar);
    searchBar.setColumns(10);

    JButton searchButton = new JButton();
    searchButton.setText("Search");
    searchButton.setBounds(654, 377, 93, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(searchButton);
    searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         {

             String userInput = searchBar.getText();

//                    GetStockData gd = new GetStockData();
//                    try 
//                    {
//                        gd.pullPriceData(userInput);
//
//                    } 
//                    catch (IOException er) 
//                    {
//                        er.printStackTrace();
//
//                    }
//
//                    String output = Double.toString(gd.getPrice());;
//                    if(output == "0")
//                    {
//                        displayBox.setText("NO STOCK FOUND");
//                    }
//                    displayBox.setText("The Price for " + userInput + ": $" + output);
                    //get to print in the table.
                    //userInput = stock ticker 
                    //ouput = price
            }
      });

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    progressBar.setValue(75);
    progressBar.setBounds(50, 412, 586, 14);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"Stock Name", "Stock Value", "Amount Owned", "Total Value"},
                {" BAC", "$13.48", "4", "$53.92"},
                {" RIG", "$8.89", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" SUNE", "$0.59", "12", "$7.08"},
                {" FCX", "$10.29", "2", "$20.58"},
                {" PBR", "$5.86", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" GE", "$31.83", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" VALE", "$4.24", "24", "$101.76"},
                {" VRX", "$27.07", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" PFE", "$30.07", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" CRC", "$1.05", "8", "$8.40"},
                {" GGB", "$1.82", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" CHK", "$4.01", "6", "$24.06"},
                {" T", "$39.37", "0", "$0.00"},
                {" F", "$13.35", "5", "$66.75"},
                {" WLL", "$7.66", "0", "$0.00"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        ));
    table.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    table.setBounds(350, 51, 395, 313);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(table);

    JTextArea txtrValue = new JTextArea();
    txtrValue.setText("Displays Cash Value");
    txtrValue.setLineWrap(true);
    txtrValue.setEditable(false);
    txtrValue.setBounds(99, 12, 172, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(txtrValue);

    JTextArea txtrCurrentPortfolioValue = new JTextArea();
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setText("Display Portfolio Value");
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setLineWrap(true);
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setEditable(false);
    txtrCurrentPortfolioValue.setBounds(376, 12, 206, 22);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(txtrCurrentPortfolioValue);

    JLabel lblCashValue = new JLabel("Cash Value:");
    lblCashValue.setBounds(24, 15, 111, 16);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(lblCashValue);

    JLabel lblPortfolioValue = new JLabel("Portfolio Value:");
    lblPortfolioValue.setBounds(283, 15, 123, 16);
    frmBgszStockSimulator.getContentPane().add(lblPortfolioValue);
}
}

/*  private class customListener implements ActionListener {
    private GUIroughdraft window;

    public customListener(GUIroughdraft window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String userInput = window.searchBar.getText();
            GetStockData gd = new GetStockData();
            try {
                gd.pullPriceData(userInput);
            } catch (IOException er) {
                er.printStackTrace();
            }
            String output = Double.toString(gd.getPrice());
            window.displayBox.setText("The Price for " + userInput + ":" + output);
    }
}*/
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested but was still unable to see the color gray anywhere on my window, was the only change you made to that one line of code?

Comment: I used the code you posted and it worked. Thank you. However, why does this chunk of code not work?                                                                           searchBar = new JTextField();
      searchBar.setText("Enter your text here");
      searchBar.setBounds(12, 300, 300, 22);
      frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(searchBar);                      searchBar.setColumns(10);

Comment: You need to specify `frmBgszStockSimulatorBuy.getContentPane().add(searchBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);` for searchBar as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default swing components are transparent. Use setOpaque(true) on the component you want to change background color, and then will it work.